# Pull request issue in merging into branch in Azure Devops

Tags: git, azure, github, azure-devops, devops

How to resolve the conflict file while pull request in Azure Devops? How can we ignore one or multiple file while merging into different branch?

Comment: Ignoring conflicts? What's the problem with resolving them? Also, these are two different questions, which both have answers here. I'd suggest a bit of research.

Comment: Note that typically you would resolve the conflicts *outside* of AzDO (or any tool). During that resolution you can also skip certain changes. To do it locally, you could merge the target branch *into* your source branch, or you could rebase your source branch *onto* the target branch. Then push (or force push) your source branch back out, and then the PR will automatically update without having any conflicts. That being said, according to [this answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77394485/184546), you may be able to resolve the conflicts directly in the web UI.

Answer (score 1):

> ***how to resolve the conflict file while pull request in azure devops.***

You can use the [**Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension**](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab) to resolve the merge conflicts on the page of Pull Request.

After installing this extension, it will add tab named "**`Conflicts`**" to the page of Pull Request. On this tab, the conflicting files and contents are shown, and you can manually update the conflicting contents to resolve the conflicts.

---

> ***How can we ignore one or multiple file while merging into different branch?***

If you want to merge particular part of changes from one branch to another, you can try using the [**cherry-pick**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/cherry-pick?view=azure-devops&tabs=browser) feature on Azure Repos.

> ***`Git cherry-pick copies the changes from one or more source branch commits to a target branch. Unlike merge or rebase, cherry-pick lets you select specific source branch commits.`***

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to ignore particular files when merging to another branch, you can try to use the Git attributes to set some merge strategies for these files. More details, see "[**Git Attributes - Merge Strategies**](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Attributes#_merge_strategies)".

Comment: Cherry-pick doesn't ignore files, this is a bit misleading.

Comment: @MohammadAslam, I have updated my above answer with more suggestions. You can check and try it.